# How to use a changing variable across two php files

Tags: php, global

I want to create a folder on my server named after the current date. My variable would be: `$foldername = date('HisYmd');`

I have two scripts that both upload one file to the folder, one of the scripts creates the folder when the submit button is pressed, the other script uploads bigger files so it's like 5 seconds slower.

So basically my question is, how can I lock `$foldername` for the two scripts so that it doesn't change every second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use session variables.

Example:

in file 1:

```
if(!session_id())
 session_start();
$_SESSION['foldername'] = $foldername  = date('HisYmd');
```

in file 2:

```
if(!session_id())
 session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['foldername']) && !empty($_SESSION['foldername']))
  $foldername = $_SESSION['foldername'];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried it and it still creates two different folders for me, with a few seconds difference between them.

http://gyazo.com/76e3cd06976bbbaf72e8311533e72079

Comment: Oh I switched the code between files (file 1 to file 2 and vice versa) and it worked now :) Thank you so much!